# how do I put different theme in subdomains in drupal?

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

There is a site in drupal example: www.example.com.

I have their sub-domain sites like: sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, sub3.example.com.

I need to put 3 different themes in these sub-domains.
how should I achieve this? which file should I configure?

Do all the sub-domains have same settings.php file or do all the sub-domains have different settings.php of their own?

Comment: are you using domain_access module to achieve the multi-domain feature? Or Drupal multisite feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one site serving all domains use "Domain access" module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/domain

It allows you to set different theme per domain.

If not...then set different theme for every site the regular way.

**Update:**

Your local host you are visiting should have some (local) i.p. address which you also can use to visit your (multi) site. i.e.

http://192.168.33.22/

Then you should edit "hosts" file on your computer. That file is some kind of internal DNS server and there you can set pairs domain/ip address, so when you visit domain you set you'll be sent to ip address you set. Very useful when i.e. your domain is not ready yet, but your host is..for testing. At end of hosts file add:

```
192.168.33.22   my_first_domain.com
192.168.33.22   my_second_domain.com
...
```

So they all will point to your web server's i.p. address

Depending on OS you are using you can find hosts file:

```
Mac: /private/etc/hosts
Windows: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
Linux (Ubuntu): /etc/hosts
```

Or if it's not there...google a bit for you OS.

Comment: I am trying to do this in my local, with localhost. how do i do it?

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your instance into multi-sites mode, and then, place your theme into sites/sitename-a.com/themes, sites/sitename-b.com/themes…

You can find informations about this [here, on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base)

Works also for domain-specific libraries or modules.

And for shared modules/themes, continue to place them into sites/all

Comment: This can be done in local host also? Because when I tried in local it dint work :(